# Spivak Calculus 5-23

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation

Consider a function $f$ with the following property: if $g$ is any function for which $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)$ does not exist.  Prove that this happens iff either $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists and is $\neq 0$ (condition 1) or $\lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)| = \infty$ (condition 2).

My attempt:
I did not have any trouble proving the converse (proving condition 1 implies $f$ has the property and proving condition 2 implies $f$ has the property).  I am not sure how to proceed to prove the other direction (want to know how to prove that if $f$ has the property, then it must either satisfy condition 1 or condition 2).

The textbook states to consider the contrapositive (if neither of these two conditions holds, then there is a function $g$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist but $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)$ does exist.)

It further hints to consider separate cases: (case 1) for some $\epsilon>0$ we have $|f(x)|>\epsilon$ for all sufficiently small x. (case 2) for every $\epsilon>0$ there are arbitrary small x with $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.  In the second case, begin by choosing points $x_n$ with $|x_n| < 1/n$ and $|f(x_n)|<1/n$.

I have two main questions:

- how do I formally negate the two conditions in an attempt to prove the contrapositive (is it just [$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist or $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$] and [$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq \infty$] ?)
- I have no clue why we would consider those 2 cases

Comment: If a limit is $\infty$, do we say the limit exists or not? What's the convention in the book?

Comment: It states that the limit does not exist if it's $\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that for every $g$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ does not exist, we also have that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)g(x)$ does not exist. Towards a contradiction, suppose that both condition 1 and condition 2 fail. This means:

1. Either $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist, or $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$.
2. It is not true that $\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)|=\infty$.

We now proceed by cases as in the hint:

**Case 1**: For some $\varepsilon>0$ and some $\delta>0$, we have that $|f(x)|>\varepsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x|<\delta$. Consider the function $g=\frac{1}{f}$, defined in $(-\delta,\delta)$.

**Claim:** $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ does not exist.

**Proof:** There are two possibilities. If the limit exists and is non-zero, then the same is true of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{g(x)}$, which contradicts 1. The other option is that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$, which then gives $\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)|=\infty$, contradicting 2. $\square$

Note however that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)g(x)=1$. As a side remark, the assumption of Case 1 was useful because it implies that $f$ never vanishes in some neighbourhood of $0$, which allows us to define $g$ (try define $g$ by cases without this assumption, you'll run into trouble).

**Case 2**: Suppose for every $\varepsilon>0$ and every $\delta>0$ there is some $x$ with $|x|<\delta$ and $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$. Pick $x_n$ such that $|x_n|<\frac{1}{n}$ and $|f(x_n)|<\frac{1}{n}$. Note that this implies $x_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Define

$$
g(x):=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{n} & \text{if $x=x_n$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Obviously, $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ does not exist. However, $|f(x)g(x)|\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for every $x$, which gives $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)g(x)=0$, contrary to the hypothesis.

Comment: How would I go about finding these cases - like if we weren't given the hint, how is one suppose to find the cases by himself? Thank you for your detailed response as well

Comment: @SaranWrap Well, there are two parts to that question. First, some things become more natural with practice. I'm sure there are problems you now find trivial which used to be completely vexing. The same thing happens, to varying degrees, across mathematics. Second, from the more mathematical point of view, if you try to think about how $f$ might behave. Does it vanish near $0$? Does it do so infinitely often? Is it bounded above? Below? Asking this kind of questions can uncover something useful.

Comment: @SaranWrap You can also view this problem as a harder variation of the following: "If $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)$ exists, is it true that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ and $\lim{x\to 0}g(x)$ exist (one or both)?" The natural counterexample to consider is $f\frac{1}{f}$ for this to make sense, $f$ should be non-zero in a neighbourhood of $0$. So, that could be one of our cases. The other option is that there is a sequence $x_n\to 0$ such that $f(x_n)=0$ for every $n$. Then you can define $g(x_n)=n$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\neq x_n$. Actually, now that I think about it, this might be an easier way!